# Is there anyway to extract the public key from gpg encrypted file?

Tags: gpgpu

Consider the following scenario:
1. I generate a key pair.
2. I then distribute public key to my customer.
3. The customer uses the public key to encrypt a file and then send me the file.
4. I need to identify who the customer is.

I am wondering whether it is possible to extract public key from a gpg encrypted file?

Answer (score 2):

You have this the wrong way around: you can't identify a customer using *your public* key.

If you want to verify a sender then the message is encrypted using the *senders* *private* key which serves as the senders digital signature. The digitally "signed" and encrypted message is then sent to the receiver who can then use the *senders* *public* key to decrypt the message and reveal the original contents. This is termed **Inverse Public Key Encryption**

Also see: [Should we sign-then-encrypt, or encrypt-then-sign?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign)

Ref: [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

Comment: I have the private key. The customer encrypts the message using the public key. I just like to extract the public key that encrypted the file, the same way like extracting public key for X.509.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my answer correctly. You cannot do what you asking by distributing *your* public key.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title:
    gpg --pinentry-mode cancel --list-packets file.gpg
will give you the key-id from the encrypting key,
but will not reveal from, but to whom the file was encrypted.
In this case yourself.

credit to: https://superuser.com/questions/1409511/how-to-check-if-a-gpg-encrypted-file-is-encrypted-using-a-specific-public-key